# Adding minutes to timestamp in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a DataFrame df with 2000 rows. The first few rows look like the following:

`+--------------+----------+--+
|  Timestamp   | Duration |  |
+--------------+----------+--+
| 1/5/18 0:23  |       22 |  |
| 1/5/18 3:34  |       32 |  |
| 1/5/18 23:48 |       24 |  |
| 1/6/18 2:26  |       15 |  |
| 1/6/18 14:13 |       23 |  |
+--------------+----------+--+`

I would like to create a new column C based on the following criteria:
if Duration >= 20: then add 20 mins to the timestamp.
if Duration < 20: then null.

So, given the above information and data, the new table should look like:

`+--------------+----------+--------------+--+--+
|  Timestamp   | Duration |      C       |  |  |
+--------------+----------+--------------+--+--+
| 1/5/18 0:23  |       22 | 1/5/18 0:43  |  |  |
| 1/5/18 3:34  |       32 | 1/5/18 3:54  |  |  |
| 1/5/18 23:48 |       24 | 1/6/18 0:08  |  |  |
| 1/6/18 2:26  |       15 | Null         |  |  |
| 1/6/18 14:13 |       23 | 1/6/18 14:33 |  |  |
+--------------+----------+--------------+--+--+`

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Can you please remove the formatting and just keep the columns so it is easier to copy next time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little datetime arithmetic ought to do it.

```
df['C'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp) + pd.to_timedelta(
              np.where(df.Duration > 20, 20, np.nan), unit='m')
```

```
df['C']

0   2018-01-05 00:43:00
1   2018-01-05 03:54:00
2   2018-01-06 00:08:00
3                   NaT
4   2018-01-06 14:33:00
Name: C, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Feel free to format the result as needed:

```
df['C'] = df['C'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%y %H:%M')
```

Note: if your dates start with the dayfirst, change the Timestamp conversion code to

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp, dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')
```

So dates are handled appropriately as having the day first.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! There is still one issue. For Duration >= 20, the 'C' column is not showing the 20 mins added to the timestamp or showing null for cases where Duration < 20. For example, in the example above, the first row is still showing 1/5/18 0:23 instead of 1/5/18 0:43. And the 4th row is still showing 1/6/18 2:26 instead of null.